# react-fetch-blob when use downloadManager the progress is not called

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I use react-native-fetch-blob to download my apk, then update the application. but when I use the rfb downloadmanager config for android, the progress method is not called. what is the reason?

```
RNFetchBlob
    .config({
        addAndroidDownloads : {
            useDownloadManager : required         
            notification : true,
            mime : 'text/plain',
            description : 'File downloaded by download manager.'
        }
    })
    .fetch('GET', 'http://example.com/file/somefile')
    .then((resp) => {
      // the path of downloaded file
      resp.path()
    })..progress((received, total) => {
        console.log('progress', received / total)
    })
```

Comment: Share to us your code

Comment: @DevAS; I use as the offical use. I have read the andrid source code. it hanldes it use different way. so when we use android downloadmananger, it not use okhttp intercepteor, the progress is update by the okhttp.

Comment: what should we do then!